# How do I properly use sp_send_dbmail in a trigger?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I've created a trigger on a table called Project, the query successfully compiled however when I go to insert data into the table I get an error stating:

```
Msg 14636, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 112 [Batch Start Line 139]
No global profile is configured. Specify a profile name in the @profile_name parameter.
```

As well as:

```
Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 64 [Batch Start Line 139]
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
```

I'm not completely familiar with the sp_send_dbmail procedure but I tried to have it so when a trigger is triggered it send an email out to xxxxx@gmail.com.

```
--Create a Table to hold the project audit
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProjectAudit](
    projectId char(4) not null,
    projectName varchar(50) null, 
    fundedbudget decimal(16,2) null,
    firmFedID char(9) null,
    statusID varchar(25) null,
    projectTypeID char(4) null, 
    startDate date null,  
    projectedEndDate date null,
    projectManager char(8) null,
    dateTimeCreated smalldatetime null,
    operation varchar(50),
    userName varchar(50)
)
go

-- Project trigger
create TRIGGER trg_ProjectAudit
ON Project
After Insert,Delete,Update
AS
Begin
     declare @name varchar(50)
     declare @body varchar(100) 
     if exists(select projectId from inserted)
     BEGIN
         select @name = projectName
         from inserted
         set @name = @name + ' has been inputted into the project table.'

         INSERT INTO ProjectAudit 
         (projectId, projectName, fundedbudget, firmFedID, statusID, projectTypeID, 
         startDate, projectedEndDate, projectManager, operation, dateTimeCreated, userName)
         SELECT projectId, projectName, fundedbudget, firmFedID, statusID, projectTypeID, 
         startDate, projectedEndDate, projectManager, 'INSERT', getdate(), System_user
         FROM Inserted
         exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = 'xxxxx@gmail.com', 
         @body = @name
     END

     if exists(select projectId from deleted)
     begin
        select @name = projectName
         from deleted
         set @name = @name + ' has been deleted from the project table.'

        INSERT INTO ProjectAudit 
         (projectId, projectName, fundedbudget, firmFedID, statusID, projectTypeID, 
         startDate, projectedEndDate, projectManager, operation, dateTimeCreated, userName)
         SELECT projectId, projectName, fundedbudget, firmFedID, statusID, projectTypeID, 
         startDate, projectedEndDate, projectManager, 'DELETE', getdate(), System_user
         FROM deleted
         exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = 'xxxxx@gmail.com', 
         @body = @name  
     end



     --check if a column update
     if (update(projectid) or update(projectTypeID))
     begin
        print 'ProjectID or ProjectTypeID column was updated'
        exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = 'xxx@gmail.com',
            @body = 'Data has been updated in the project table.'   
     end
End
GO
```

Comment: If you don't have dbmail setup properly, it won't send email. Do you have a profile setup? `EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_profile_sp;` Check the account? `EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_account_sp` Then check to see if they are linked. `EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_profileaccount_sp;`

Comment: If you have all setup properly. Add the `profile name` to the `sp_send_dbmail` before `@recipients` put `@profile_name = 'yourprofilename', `

Comment: You also may want to have a `Subject` in your email. Before `@body` put `@subject = 'Your Subject Text',`

Comment: Does the sp_send_dbmail command work outside of the trigger? If not, you need to enable/configure email first.